# Determine whether the following statement is true or false.

Tags: continuity, proof-writing

The rest of the question states the following: "If true, give an explanation as to why. If false, give a counter example."

Here is the following statement:

> The set {$x:\mid x+3\mid>4$} can be drawn on the number line without lifting your pencil.

I know this is false, and I know that $x<-7$ and $x>1$. What I am really asking is how to prove this, which I have no idea how to do so. I know that this question touches upon the concept of continuity, however.

Comment: I believe it *should* suffice to say the set is disconnected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M := \{x \in \mathbb{R}: |x+3| > 4\}$

As a counterexample, find $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ with

$a < b < c$ and $a,c \in M, b \notin M$

So this shows that you can't draw the set $M$ as one line on the number line.

Comment: Nice thinking! Thank you!